# How to create a new image from an existing image and a string over it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, ios

I need to create something like: 
http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQZu06WspVUaFTn-C-YD6Pzu_oWH5NLA1Q8nPUZEdemllFIAMNn

So I need to place a user input string over an image in a specified spot, then save it in the memory.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new bitmap image context. See this for help [creating-and-drawing-on-a-new-uiimage](http://www.codza.com/creating-and-drawing-on-a-new-uiimage)
2. Draw your UIImage in `drawInRect`
3. Create black, rounded and transparent image. See this for help:
   [resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/)
4. Draw black image `drawInRect`
5. Draw your NSString text. see this for help [how-to-display-text-using-quartz-on-the-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143215/how-to-display-text-using-quartz-on-the-iphone) `drawInRect` or `drawInPoint`

Comment: Tnx for the tips, but sorry I've not understood.
Can you help me telling me how to crop (taking just an area) of an UIImage?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small code example for cropping an image.

```
- (UIImage *)croppedImageWithRect:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(scaleImage.CGImage, bounds);
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return croppedImage;
}
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

use a UItextView over an image to show such string.

Comment: And to save it, I'd make a screenshot out of it. `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.size); CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); CGRect area = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.size.width, view.size.height); CGContextDrawImage(ctx, area, view.layer.CGImage); UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); ` I'm unsure if the code is correct, but it's about the idea ;)

Comment: I've do I've taken the code of the first reply and fixed a bit, but it take the screenshot, move it upside down, and scale to fit the size I've give. It should crop.

CGSize quoteSize = CGSizeMake(320, 320);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(quoteSize); CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); CGRect area = CGRectMake(0, 0, quoteSize.width, quoteSize.height);


UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size); [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

(continue)

Comment: (part 2)

CGContextDrawImage(ctx, area, screenShot.CGImage); UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// Save image to photos UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, self, nil, nil);

Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Found!
Use that code to crop: `CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([screenShot CGImage], area);
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);`